Country Flags in NetSuite Saved Searches
We're currently handling multiple languages for our cases and we'd like to implement country flags in our saved search to save space as opposed to having a whole separate column for the language field.
Is there any way to implement this with Formula(HTML)?
I tried to use inline CSS mentioned here with no luck. It just shows  as a text: How do I view country flags on Windows 10 through HTML?
